# Como copiar certos Bytes de um tipo Data em Swift

Tags: swift, conversão

Como exemplo eu android para fazer o que pretende uso o seguinte:

```
byte[] byte = ....;
byte[] resultado = Arrays.copyOfRange(byte, 1,3);
```

E pretendo fazer o mesmo mas em Swift sendo que neste caso em vez de ser o tipo byte[] é do tipo Data.

O que tentei fazer foi o seguinte:

`let newNumbers:Data = dataBytes[1...3]`

mas dá o seguinte erro "Cannot subscript a value of type 'Data' with an index of type 'CountableClosedRange'", algum me consegue ajudar aqui?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que voce está tentando forçar newNumbers ser do tipo `Data` mas o resultado do subscript é do tipo `MutableRangeReplaceableRandomAccessSlice`. Basta voce inicializar um novo objeto Data com esse objeto:

```
let string = "0123456789"
let stringData = Data(string.utf8)
let subdata = Data(stringData[1...3])
print(Array(subdata))  // "[49, 50, 51]
```

outra opção é usar o método `subdata(in range: Range<Data.Index>) -> Data` que retorna um objeto do tipo Data, mas voce precisa passar uma `half-open range` em vez de countable closed range. (ex.: `..<` em vez de `...`)

```
let string = "0123456789"
let stringData = Data(string.utf8)
let subdata = stringData.subdata(in: 1..<4)
print(Array(subdata))  // "[49, 50, 51]
```